# Load post content WordPress in div

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, html

I have a Wordpress with a home page where a div on the left that shows all titles in the last 5 post.

To the right is an empty div with scroll bar.

What I need is that when you click any of the post title, post content is loaded into the div on the right and not on another page.

Any idea how to do it with jQuery?

Thank you,
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely straightforward.

You'll want to give your menu links a name or class that is the id for the post-content. The post id will be in the article header - check the source.

You can then set up a click event for the menu links and access that id through jQuery with something like `$(this).attr('name')`

Then you'll need to read a tutorial about loading WP content via ajax. e.g. 
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress/

It's not too tricky, but can be a a bit fiddly.